# Testing WPF application with Coded UI - How to get Stability in Tests with UIMaps

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, prism, coded-ui-tests

I am implementing Testing automation with Coded UI on A WPF (Prism) based application.

I have a big stability problem. The recorder creates the UIMap for me, then I define methods and try to reuse these methods to build test.

Basically, the UIMaps that are created are frequently unable to locate the element in the APP even if we use AutomationID and such names.

What are we doing wrong in odred to get stable, extendable uiMaps?

Is there any work method that we should follow? Is there any framework, or programming tricks when we develop in WPF?

Do you have a set of best practices?

I come here because I could not find any suitable documentation how to design the tests or the app to have efficient Automated testing with coded UI on WPF App.

Comment: Not an actual answer, more of a suggestion: don't. If you test your app up to the view models, ignoring the views, you remove the whole stability problems. Just run your app without wpf (super easy, you just have to swap out the region manager), and make your tests execute commands on view models instead of simulating button clicks. Leave the actual ui testing to manual test...

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. Do you have any good documentation for this?

Comment: Not really, at least I found none when I was faced the problem. But it turned out to not be complicated at all. Essentially you create another bootstrapper for your tests that registers a `RegionManager` that does all the view model creation and navigation, but never shows a shell. It just stores the view models "visible" in all the regions and your tests access the view models to execute commands and check properties whether the right things a displayed...

Comment: While separation of concerns is definitely good, there comes a point where you have to test the UI (even if just that it is binding correctly to view model).  I would recommend writing the "UI Maps" by hand and no using record and play back.  This will *greatly* improve reuse of your modeled components.  For suggestions on how to do this, see my website, http://codeduiexamples.com, or other open source solutions like CUITe https://github.com/icnocop/cuite and white https://github.com/TestStack/White